# Finding file permission using C

Tags: c, file, permissions, copy, posix

How do I find the permission of a file using C?

I'm making a file copying program and everything works fine except it does not duplicate the file permissions on the new file.

Right now i'm using fcntl.h and open() and creat() to open the file and make the destination file but it is losing the permisisons.

I was hoping for a command that can read the file permission in to a number like 0644 or 0777 then I use that number in creat() to make that file. Does such a command exist?

*EDIT*
Thank you for all the help, I got it working with the following code

```
struct stat status;
mode_t permissions;
stat("path_to_file", &status);
permissions = status.st_mode;'
```

then use permissions inside the creat();

Comment: How about [`stat`/`lstat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) or [`fstat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Use [stat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html).

The above link would also provide you sample code!

```
/* Print out type, permissions, and number of links. */
printf("%10.10s", sperm (statbuf.st_mode));
printf("%4d", statbuf.st_nlink);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `stat()` function will get what you need: http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat

Be aware though that your `umask()` (http://linux.die.net/man/2/umask) will have an effect on what permissions actually get used.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)

```
   struct stat sb;
   mode_t file_permision; // read file permission before copy

   if (stat("source_file_name", &sb) == -1) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

 file_permision = sb.st_mode;

//Then create new file

 creat("destination_file_name", file_permision );
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with the following code using your example. 
'struct stat status;
 mode_t permissions;
 stat(argV[i], &status);
 permissions = status.st_mode;' 
then use permissions inside the creat();